# How to read the delta of a table from DB into Kafka Producer in java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to use DB data as my Kafka producer in my java code. The source data grows continuously (say 20 rows per second). The whole data is read from DB and added to the Kafka topic every time a new record is inserted into the DB table. I want only the newly appended rows to be sent to the topic (ie. if the table holds 10 rows already and 4 more rows are appended to it, only those 4 rows need to be sent to the topic).

Is there a way to achieve this in java, provided we can also use the Kafka API??

Comment: Can you post some more info? like the query you're running to get records from the db?

Comment: CREATE TABLE EMP_DETAILS
(EMPID NUMBER,
ENAME VARCHAR2(100),
DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER,
SALARY NUMBER,
JOB_ID VARCHAR2(3),
HIREDATE DATE,
COMM NUMBER);  
  
SELECT  EMPID, ENAME, SALARY
FROM  EMP_DETAILS;

Answer (score 3):

A much easier route would be to use change-data-capture to feed the changes from the database to the Kafka topic. Trying to build this yourself is reinventing a wheel that has already been perfected ;-)

What's your source database? For proprietary RDBMS (Oracle, DB2, MS SQL etc) you have commercial tools such as GoldenGate, Attunity, DBVisit and so on. For open source RDBMS (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL) you should look at the open source [Debezium](http://debezium.io/docs/tutorial/) tool. 
All of these CDC tools integrate directly with Kafka.

The other option you have, depending on your use case, scale, etc is just to pull changed rows from the database using the [JDBC Kafka Connect connector](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html). This is not as flexible or scalable as CDC, but still useful and easier than trying to poll the database yourself.

Comment: Thanks Robin!!! I'm using the source DB as MS SQLServer. I have gone through the link on JDBC Source Connector but couldn't get a logic to achieve the target result. Can you help me provide a sample code to implement JDBC Source Connector logic which I can use it in my eclipse IDE? I also prefer the "Incremental Query Mode" as "Timestamp and Incrementing Columns". TIA

Comment: That's the point with Kafka Connect - you don't need to run an Eclipse IDE, you just pass it a configuration file :) Check out these for reference: https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Comment: Sorry to ask this way, I'm very new to Kafka or any other Kafka related technologies. If possible, can you provide me a details step by step approach to achieve the desired results.  
  
All I want is to "Pull data using JDBC Kafka Connect connector, based on a timestamp column & Incrementing columns in the source table to identify new and modified rows"

Comment: Those blogs I gave you are literally a step by step approach. Did you read them? Which bits aren't clear?

Comment: Yes I have gone thru them, but I'm expecting a solution which I can use it in Java side and not the confluent ways